# Plot survival and hazard function of survreg using curve()

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, weibull, parametric-equations

I have the following survreg model:

```
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(time = (ev.time), event = ev) ~ age, 
    data = my.data, dist = "weib")
             Value Std. Error    z        p
(Intercept) 4.0961     0.5566 7.36 1.86e-13
age         0.0388     0.0133 2.91 3.60e-03
Log(scale)  0.1421     0.1208 1.18 2.39e-01
Scale= 1.15 

Weibull distribution
```

I would like to plot the **hazard** function and the **survival** function based on the above estimates.
I don't want to use `predict()` or `pweibull()` (as presented here [Parametric Survival](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2010spring/ecol/562/001/docs/lectures/lecture24.htm) or here [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151591/how-to-plot-the-survival-curve-generated-by-survreg-package-survival-of-r).

I would like to use the `curve()` function. Any ideas how I can accomplish this? It seems the Weibull function of the survreg uses other definitions of scale and shape than the usual (and different that for example rweibull).

**UPDATE:** I guess what I really require it to express hazard / survival as a function of the estimates `Intercept`, `age (+ other potential covariates)`, `Scale` without using any ready made `*weilbull` function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your parameters are:

`scale=exp(Intercept+beta*x)` in your example and lets say for age=40

```
scale=283.7
```

your shape parameter is the reciprocal of the scale that the model outputs

```
shape=1/1.15
```

Then the hazard is:

```
curve((shape/scale)*(x/scale)^(shape-1), from=0,to=12,ylab=expression(hat(h)(t)), col="darkblue",xlab="t", lwd=5)
```

The cumulative hazard function is:

```
curve((x/scale)^(shape), from=0,to=12,ylab=expression(hat(F)(t)), col="darkgreen",xlab="t", lwd=5)
```

The Survival function is 1-the cumulative hazard function, so:

```
curve(1-((x/scale)^(shape)), from=0,to=12,ylab=expression(hat(S)(t)), col="darkred",xlab="t", lwd=5, ylim=c(0,1))
```

Also check out the `eha` package, and the function `hweibull` and `Hweibull`

[image: Weibull Functions]

Answer (score 11):

The [first link you provided](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2010spring/ecol/562/001/docs/lectures/lecture24.htm) actually has a clear explanation on the theory of how this works, along with a lovely example. (Thank you for this, it is a nice resource I will use in my own work.)

To use the `curve` function, you will need to pass some function as an argument. It is true that the `*weibull` family of functions use a different parameterization for the Weibull than `survreg`, but it can be easily transformed, as explained your first link. Also, from the documentation in `survreg`:

> There are multiple ways to parameterize a Weibull distribution. The survreg 
>   function imbeds it in a general location-scale familiy, which is a 
>   different parameterization than the rweibull function, and often leads
>   to confusion.
>
> ```
>   survreg's scale  =    1/(rweibull shape)
>   survreg's intercept = log(rweibull scale)
> ```

Here is an implementation of that simple transformation:

```
# The parameters
intercept<-4.0961
scale<-1.15

par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(5.1,5.1,4.1,2.1)) # Make room for the hat.
# S(t), the survival function
curve(pweibull(x, scale=exp(intercept), shape=1/scale, lower.tail=FALSE), 
      from=0, to=100, col='red', lwd=2, ylab=expression(hat(S)(t)), xlab='t',bty='n',ylim=c(0,1))
# h(t), the hazard function
curve(dweibull(x, scale=exp(intercept), shape=1/scale)
      /pweibull(x, scale=exp(intercept), shape=1/scale, lower.tail=FALSE), 
      from=0, to=100, col='blue', lwd=2, ylab=expression(hat(h)(t)), xlab='t',bty='n')
par(mfrow=c(1,1),mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,2.1))
```

[image: Survival and hazard functions]

I understand that you mentioned in your answer that you did not want to use the `pweibull` function, but I am guessing that you did not want to use it because it uses a different parameterization. Otherwise, you could simply write your own version of `pweibull` that uses that `survreg`'s parameterization:

```
my.weibull.surv<-function(x,intercept,scale) pweibull(x,scale=exp(intercept),shape=1/scale,lower.tail=FALSE)
my.weibull.haz<-function(x,intercept,scale) dweibull(x, scale=exp(intercept), shape=1/scale) / pweibull(x,scale=exp(intercept),shape=1/scale,lower.tail=FALSE)

curve(my.weibull.surv(x,intercept,scale),1,100,lwd=2,col='red',ylim=c(0,1),bty='n')
curve(my.weibull.haz(x,intercept,scale),1,100,lwd=2,col='blue',bty='n')
```

---

As I mentioned in the comments, I don't know why you would do this (unless this is homework), but you could handcode `pweibull` and `dweibull` if you like:

```
my.dweibull <- function(x,shape,scale) (shape/scale) * (x/scale)^(shape-1) * exp(- (x/scale)^shape)
my.pweibull <- function(x,shape,scale) exp(- (x/scale)^shape)
```

Those definitions come straight out of `?dweibull`. Now just wrap those, slower, untested functions instead of `pweibull` and `dweibull` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate email but I DO NOT want to use any `*weibull` function either. Is it possible to express the hazard as a function of `Intercept`, `age (+other covariates)`, and `scale`?

Comment: Hm, perhaps you missed my final paragraph, where I show you how to write a function that is simply a wrapper of `pweibull`. I don't know why you would want to rewrite `pweibull`, as it is coded in C, and is very fast and well-tested. Unless this is just homework. Anyway, I show you how to handcode `pweibull` and `dweibull`.

Comment: I think the OP misses the math connection between the R output and the hazard/survival function