# How to plot the survival curve generated by multi-variate survreg

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, weibull

This question follows on from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151591/how-to-plot-the-survival-curve-generated-by-survreg-package-survival-of-r)
in that we want to plot a multi-variate model.

Lets say we want to plot the Survival function from the example in `survreg` from the [package release notes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf)

Where the model is

```
survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + strata(sex), lung)
```

From what I understand the [following problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236939/plot-survival-and-hazard-function-of-survreg-using-curve) seems to address the problem, but does not provide a data set and only uses one variable. Where in this example, we have two continuous variables and one factor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plot for the predicted survival curve for hypothetical individual with mean of lung$age and the mode of lung$ph.ecog (following the example in the help page):

```
?predict.survreg
pct <- 1:98/100
ptime <- predict(res, newdata=data.frame(ph.ecog=1, age=62.44737, sex=1),  type='quantile',
                  p=pct, se=TRUE)
 matplot(cbind(ptime$fit, ptime$fit + 2*ptime$se.fit,
                          ptime$fit - 2*ptime$se.fit)/30.5, 1-pct,
         xlab="Months", ylab="Survival", type='l', lty=c(1,2,2), col=1)
```

[image]

Comment: and then if we were to want to create a second curve on the same plot. Lets say someone with of the opposing sex. Would we just use the `lines`function or the same `predict` with `add=TRUE`?

Comment: I would re-run `predict.survreg` with new values and then use `matlines`, perhaps with a different `col`-argument.

Comment: @42 is there a way to adjust this result to allow x and y to have different number of rows?  Apparently matplot only works if x and y are vectors of the same length.

Comment: I would need a more complete problem description since in the current use case what I would see as the "Y values" are generated from "X-values", but I'm speculating that you are looking for `expand.grid` to be applied to your X values before generating Y's. If its title has the string "surv" in it or a tag of `[survival-analysis]`, I'll see it.