# How to predict survivor function for a given event time in a parametric survival model

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis

Assume a parametric survival model:

```
surv <- Surv(time, event)
surv.reg.t <- survreg(surv ~ 1, dist = "t", data = myData)
```

It is possible to predict the percentile for one given case by

```
pct=1:9000/10000
predict.t = predict(surv.reg.t, newdata=data.frame(F = "X"), type='quantile', p=pct, se=TRUE)
```

This is the way described in [How to predict survival probabilities in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27410588/2107731) and [How to make prediction in survival analysis using R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/127506/45140). In these answers the value of the survivor function is given, and the event time is predicted.

However, how to predict the survivor function given some event time `x`? Is there a way to use `survreg.predict`? If not how can I do this using the coefficients of `surv.reg.t` when the distribution `dist="t"` is used?

Comment: You have x (outcome of the predict-operation) and y ( the `pct`-object) of the survival function ... so just find position of the closest `predict.t`  and that will be the index to use into the the pct vector.

Comment: @42- That's the rocky path I would like to avoid. Is there not an easier way using `predict(..., type='response')`?

Comment: It didn't seem particularly "rocky" when I did it.