# Plotting a simple survreg Weibul survivall fit

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, weibull

This is a simpler variation of the question that has been answered at [How to plot the survival curve generated by survreg (package survival of R)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151591/how-to-plot-the-survival-curve-generated-by-survreg-package-survival-of-r?newreg=5662d96d94194ce59b9c20973418f78)

```
# Create simple Weibull survival fit using library(survival)
  surmo<-survreg( Surv(validtimes, status)~1, dist="weibull")

# Getting Kaplan-Meier
  fKM<-survfit( Surv(validtimes, status)~1)

# Plot Kaplan-Meier
  plot(fKM,xlab="Time,Days",conf.int=TRUE,mark.time=TRUE,ylab="Fraction",main="Kaplan-Meier Plot")
```

Everything up to this worked fine without any issues.

Problems arose when I wanted to overlay the predicted Weibull fit  on the data. Based on the example I used.

```
 pct <- seq(.01,.99,by=.01)
 maxvalidtimes<-max(validtimes)
# Getting the Weibull lines to overlay
  lines(predict(surmo,newdata=list(1:maxvalidtimes),type="quantile",p=pct),1-pct,col="red")
```

I get an error

> Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

I assumed the problem was from the term:
       newdata=list(1:maxvalidtimes)

I tried to delete the newdata term and also setting newdata=list(1:99) to no avail.

I tried the same thing in the flexsurv package and I got the exact plots I wanted, with little effort.

```
 # Using flexsurv package here
  surmof  <- flexsurvreg( Surv(validtimes, status)~1,dist='weibull')
  plot(surmof,mark.time=TRUE,xlab="Time,Days",ylab="Fraction",main="FlexSurv Plot")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't offer any data, I'm going to modify the last example in the `?predict.survreg` page which uses the `lung` dataset. You don't need any newdata since you only want a quantile-type plot and that requires a vector argument given to `p`.

```
lfit <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data=lung)
pct <- 1:98/100   # The 100th percentile of predicted survival is at +infinity
ptime <- predict(lfit,  type='quantile',
                  p=pct, se=TRUE)
 str(ptime)
#------------
List of 2
 $ fit   : num [1:228, 1:98] 12.7 12.7 12.7 12.7 12.7 ...
 $ se.fit: num [1:228, 1:98] 2.89 2.89 2.89 2.89 2.89 ...
```

So you actually have way too many data point and if you look at the 228 lines of data in `ptime` you will find that every row is the same, so just use the first row.

```
identical( ptime$fit[1,], ptime$fit[2,])
#[1] TRUE


 str(ptime$fit[1,])
# num [1:98] 12.7 21.6 29.5 36.8 43.8 ...
```

So you have a predicted time for every quantile and remember that a survival function is just 1 minus the quantile function and that the y-values are the given quentiles while its the times that form the x-values:

```
 plot(x=ptime$fit[1,], y=1-pct, type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @42-. That was it. I used this small modification based on your suggestion and it worked.

      lines(predict(surmo,type="quantile",p=pct)[1,],1-pct,col="red",lwd=2)